# Is there a way to advance the scanner only a by a single or n amount of characters in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

To give one example what if you had a time: 20:30 and you only want to know the minutes of that time (I know you can use `LocalTime.parse()` and then `getMinute()`, but keep in mind, this is just an example, so please pretend you can't do that for second), is there a way to advance the scanner only a certain number of lines and then invoke `nextInt()` once you reach the minutes part? every method of scanning I know so far only scans until a whitespace or newline.

Comment: That'd be an odd way to go about it. Just read the next token and then parse out the part you want.  The **design** of Scanner is token-based.

Comment: Thank you J.Backus, that's useful to know

Answer (score 1):

You can set the delimiter on a scanner.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
input.useDelimiter(":|\r");

int hr = scanner.nextInt();
int min = scanner.nextInt();
int sec = scanner.nextInt();
 
System.out.println(hr + " " + min + " " + sec);
```

For input of `10:21:34`

Prints

```
10 21 34
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many characters you want to advance, use [`skip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#skip(java.lang.String)).

For example, if you want to skip 100 characters:

```
scanner.skip("(?s).{100}");
```

If you want to skip 5 lines instead,

```
scanner.skip("(?:.+(?:\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])){5}");
```

If you don't know how many characters to skip, and just want to find the next substring looks like a time, use [`findWithinHorizon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon(java.lang.String,%20int)):

```
String timeString = scanner.findWithinHorizon("\\d\\d:\\d\\d", 0);
// then you can use LocalTime.parse to parse "timeString"
```

Comment: Okay thank you, I found it difficult to word my question, but the skip method is pretty much exactly what I am looking for, thanks again, but just one question, what does (?s) mean in java regex?

Comment: It enables the `s` option, which makes `.` match new lines also. @Poobean

Comment: @Poobean If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!